# Spark - SELECT WHERE or filtering?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What's the difference between selecting with a where clause and filtering in Spark? 
Are there any use cases in which one is more appropriate than the other one?

When do I use

```
DataFrame newdf = df.select(df.col("*")).where(df.col("somecol").leq(10))
```

and when is

```
DataFrame newdf = df.select(df.col("*")).filter("somecol <= 10")
```

more appropriate?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

According to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where) "**`where()` is an alias for `filter()`**"

`filter(condition)`
Filters rows using the given condition.
`where()` is an alias for `filter()`.

**Parameters**: condition – a `Column` of `types.BooleanType` or a string of SQL expression.

```
>>> df.filter(df.age > 3).collect()
[Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
>>> df.where(df.age == 2).collect()
[Row(age=2, name=u'Alice')]

>>> df.filter("age > 3").collect()
[Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
>>> df.where("age = 2").collect()
[Row(age=2, name=u'Alice')]
```

Comment: I know its been a while since you've answered this, but is there a significant performance difference between using Column or using a sql string to filter?

Comment: @Megan - There isn't a significant performance difference between using Column or strings when filtering.  They both generate the same physical plans, so they'll be executed the same.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 19):

As Yaron mentioned, there isn't any difference between `where` and `filter`.

`filter` is an overloaded method that takes a column or string argument.  The performance is the same, regardless of the syntax you use.

[image: filter overloaded method]

We can use `explain()` to see that all the different filtering syntaxes generate the same Physical Plan.  Suppose you have a dataset with `person_name` and `person_country` columns.  All of the following code snippets will return the same Physical Plan below:

```scala
df.where("person_country = 'Cuba'").explain()
df.where($"person_country" === "Cuba").explain()
df.where('person_country === "Cuba").explain()
df.filter("person_country = 'Cuba'").explain()
```

These all return this Physical Plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [person_name#152, person_country#153]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(person_country#153) && (person_country#153 = Cuba))
   +- *(1) FileScan csv [person_name#152,person_country#153] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/matthewpowers/Documents/code/my_apps/mungingdata/spark2/src/test/re..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(person_country), EqualTo(person_country,Cuba)], ReadSchema: struct<person_name:string,person_country:string>
```

The syntax doesn't change how filters are executed under the hood, but the file format / database that a query is executed on does.  Spark will execute the same query differently on Postgres (predicate pushdown filtering is supported), Parquet (column pruning), and CSV files.  [See here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/filter-where/) for more details.