# Is boolean indexing in PySpark officially supported?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Today I discovered you can filter a PySpark DataFrame via boolean indexing:

```
In [3]: df.show()
+-----+---+
|name1|  v|
+-----+---+
| john|1.0|
|  sam|4.0|
|  meh|3.0|
+-----+---+

In [6]: df[df['v']>2.0].show()
+-----+---+
|name1|  v|
+-----+---+
|  sam|4.0|
|  meh|3.0|
+-----+---+
```

A common way to do this is to use PySpark's `filter` function, e.g. [Spark - SELECT WHERE or filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867472/spark-select-where-or-filtering). But is the above syntax documented and officially supported? I like this syntax because it's consistent with that in Pandas (where the `filter` function means something else entirely).

Comment: It is supported because we're working towards a pandas-like syntax, but I do not think it is officially documented.